# Problems connecting Huion H420 Drawing tablet to android tablet

Tags: tablet, usb-on-the-go, drawing

I had bought a USB-OTG cable for the sole purpose of connecting my Huion H420 Drawing Tablet. When I connected it, it recognized it as a mouse, but no cursor showed up when I hovered my pen over, and if I clicked, it would only click the middle of the screen. I know Wacom Tablets work, because I saw a question on here that had it work for a Wacom tablet. Maybe its not compatible with the Huion H420, or is there any workaround?

Comment: Those devices likely need a driver which Android doesn't necessarily have...